# Possible to have super-high resolution monitor, and auto-focus eyeglasses?

Tags: display, fonts, resolution, productivity

I was thinking about if there was a super high resolution monitor - like 16 times more pixels than standard high def tv, would it be possible to set the font sizes really small on apps that run on the monitor and then where some eyeglasses that automatically magnify and focus where your eyes are looking on the monitor.  For example there could be camera that is mounted on monitor and detects how far your eyes are from the screen and what part of screen your eyes are looking at, and then the camera would send message to the have the eyeglasses automatically focus.

This way the monitor, because fonts are super small, would be able to display much more text.

I'm a computer programmer and having more text is very useful because I don't have to scroll around as much then.  I already have my fonts about as small as I can take and still see them.

Comment: Why zoom at all, when you could just have little LCDs that show text at normal resolutions...

Comment: You actually commit an antithesis here. Just having more text on a screen doesn't mean it will be helpful to you, specially if you can't read it easily enough. Let's say that there are good (and health related) reasons why most characters in everyday are in a range between 2 to 8 mm. One of those is that the bigger the screen, the farther away you should need to be.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about 4K displays which cost an arm and leg currently.

Technically what you are saying is not impossible.
Here's how it may be done:

Windows already has a magnifier tool. You can perhaps buy Kinect for Windows and write some program yourself that will control the magnifier depending on where you are looking and all.

All of this will however be experimental stuff and will typically be far from flawless.

A simpler and cheaper option would be buying multiple displays and setting them up so that you don't have to scroll much.

Comment: At work right now I have one of the highest resolutions possible.  It is some giant HP monitor they put in about 6 months ago.  I'm probably getting a tumor for all the radiation it puts off.

Comment: I do like the auto-magnify you mentioned.  I can see this down the road some software firm doing this.   One possibility is apparently you can get super vision in UK that gives 20/10 vision using advanced laser surgery.   Not sure if they offer it in the usa yet.

Comment: Well the technology is definitely on its way. 4K displays(thats literally 4 times 1080p) are here and eye tracking is sort of done by Samsung Galaxy android devices with so called smart scroll...If only you could put them together...